# AspNet Core + Vue.js : User disappear in Controller

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, vue.js

I created a new AspNet .Core + Vue.js app (using [this template](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)).

I use OAuth2 & the authentication systeme included in AspNet core to login (via Patreon), and when I disable the Vue app (delete the content of boot.ts), everything works, my User is correct, even in the Controllers.

But once the Vue.js is activated, black magic appear :

- The original login works
- The User is correct ONLY IN RAZOR PAGES
- The User is not correctly in my controllers (it's an anonymous user).

Code used in my razor page, which always works :

```
@if (User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
{
    <div id='app-root'>Loading...</div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" href="/logout">Sign out</a>
}
else
{
    <h1>Welcome, anonymous</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="/login">Sign in</a>
}
```

My Controller :

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts() {
    [...]
    var data = User; //User without data when the Vue app is activated
    [...]
}
```

My Vue.js routes :

```
const routes = [
{ path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
{ path: '/counter', component: require('./components/counter/counter.vue.html') },
{ path: '/fetchdata', component: require('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue.html') }
];
```

And, to finish, samples of my Startup.cs :

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout")
        });

        app.Map("/login", builder =>
        {
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("Patreon",
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
            });
        });

        app.Map("/logout", builder =>
        {
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            });
        });
```

I'm not used to handle authentication, and I'm a newbie in Vue.js, so I certainly made a mistake somewhere.

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, the response was obvious : in the vue app, I called my api with a simple fetch method..... **without sending the Asp authentication cookie**.

So now, it looks like this :

```
fetch('/api[...]', { credentials: "same-origin"})
```

Subject closed.